# Lagrange Multipliers Question

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the points on 
$$
4x^2+ 9y^2= 36
$$
closest and farthest from $P(1,1)$. I some how ended up with a quartic equation and it has complex roots. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: How did you get that quartic equation, and what equation is it?

Comment: 46656L^4 - 33696L^3 + 8208L^2 - 792L + 23 = 0

Comment: Before you even start calculating, first draw the problem.  I think it might be very helpful to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is $P(1,1)$?

Comment: You can parametrize the curve as $x=3\cos t,\ y=2 \sin t.$ The derivative of the squared distance from $(1,1)$ to that, if set to zero, is not *really* simple, but it's a start.

Comment: @Math1000 $P(1,1)$ is a notation often used for the point whose coordinates are 1,1 for x,y.

Comment: I figured as much, but it wasn't stated explicitly so I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers are not necessary here. If $r(t)=(3\cos t,2\sin t)$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ then the point $t^*\in[0,\pi/2]$ which minimizes $\|r(t^*)-(1,1)\|$ has normal vector in the direction of $(1,1)$, and the point which maximizes the distance is the point on the curve $r(t)$ furthest from $r(t^*)$.

Comment: If you don’t show us your work, it’ll require clairvoyance on our part to show you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are minimizing/maximizing here is the distance function given by
$$d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2}$$. WLOG, one could minimizing/maximizing the function $d^2=D$ instead since then the algebra is simpler. Define $g(x,y) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 - 36$ and let $\lambda$ be the Lagrange multiplier. Using method of Lagrange multiplier, you need to solve the following system of equations together with the constraint $g(x,y)=0$.
\begin{alignat*}{3}
2(x-1) & = D_x && = \lambda g_x && = 8x.\\
2(y-1) & = D_y && = \lambda g_y && = 18y.\\
& g(x,y) && = 0.
\end{alignat*}

Comment: I didn't do the algebra but I trust you can do it yourself. Let me know if anything is unclear thou.